# Объявление структуры, что скрывает под собой запись под катом?

Tags: c, c++, linux

Не первый раз натыкаюсь на такую запись, помогите понять ее суть.
    **struct ip_mc_list   __rcu   *mc_list;**

В комментариях к ответу [[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), все разобрано. За что огромное спасибо [[[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) и [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)

Comment: осмелюсь предположить что ip_mc_list __rcu - это макрос

Comment: Встречный вопрос: что означает "под катом"?

Несколько раз уже встречал такое выражение, но его смысл до меня не доходит.

Comment: @avp Кат -- палач. Соответственно "запись под палачём".

Comment: @alexlz, это жирненький текст такой? 

--

Кстати, такую древнюю феню я уже не разумею. Вообще считал, что эта наколка на лбу (в старое время) означала - каторжник. Но могу ошибаться.

Comment: @perfect, макрос с символом пробела в названии?

Comment: ну значит это два макроса как мне кажется

Comment: Собственно ниже товарищи @avp и @KoVadim все расписали.

Comment: "Под катом" -- это от тега `<lj-cut>`, который отделял текст постинга, попадающий в общий список, от текста, который доступен лишь если открыть постинг. В переносном смысле -- "загляните в вопрос" или там "spoiler alert".

Comment: @avp, @VladD я просто не читаю/не пришу в ЖЖ. Соответственно не знал. Велик могучим русский языка.

Comment: @alexlz, я тоже. Теперь будем знать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что это [отсюда](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler.h#L21).

```
#ifdef CONFIG_SPARSE_RCU_POINTER
# define __rcu          __attribute__((noderef, address_space(4)))
#else
# define __rcu
#endif
```

Вообще список файлов с __rcu [здесь](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=__rcu)

**update**

А подробнее о механизме синхронизации RCU (Read-copy-update) можно почитать [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org /wiki/Read-copy-update).

А вот [здесь](http://lwn.net/Articles/376011/) писатели ядра обсуждают корректность использования этого атрибута в разных местах.

Comment: Кстати, гугл работает нормально. Возможно Вы просто хотели задать "тестовый" вопрос?

Comment: а вот и не угадали, список я этот видел. Информацию попытался найти, до того как сюда лезть. Меня интересует сама запись, не стоит придерживаться именно к этим названиям переменных и т.д.

struct type var *pointer; - что это означает?
Было бы struct type var; - это было бы объявление структуры var типа type. Так зачем там указатель?

Comment: Вас смущает слово `struct` вначале?

Comment: @KoVadim, нет, меня смущает указатель в конце. Какую роль он тут играет?

Comment: указывает, что это указатель. `struct ip_mc_list __rcu *mc_list;` - это просто объявление переменной типа указатель на структуру.

Comment: @mordvincevD, так Вас не загадочно стоящее `__rcu` интересует?

Откровено не понял вопроса

    Так зачем там указатель?

Например в `/include/linux/igmp.h` в `struct ip_mc_socklist` строчка 

    struct ip_mc_socklist __rcu *next_rcu;

Это вопрос? Если да, то связывает структуры в односвязный список. А что еще может быть? 

Если нет, то приведите конкретные примеры кода (лучше в тексте вопроса), попробуем разобраться.

И, кстати, что для Вас означает "под катом"? Только объясните толково, как будто бы я вообще эфиоп.

Comment: Т.е. мы объявляем структуру __rcu типа ip_mc_list, которая будет являться указателем на mc_list?

Comment: "под катом" это от английского слова "cut" в значении "линия отреза" (вспомните, как в некоторых случаях изображается пунктирная линия с ножницами). В данном случае означает "кат" обозначает некую линию раздела вопроса на начало и тело.

@mordvincevD это не объявление новой структуры, это объявление переменной. Именно поэтому я и спросил, "Вас смущает слово `struct`".

Comment: "...связывает структуры в односвязный список" и "это объявление переменной" - это взаимосвязано?
@KoVadim, извините за твердолобость, какого типа получается переменная?

Comment: я же писал - указатель на структуру типа `ip_mc_list __rcu`.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, понял. Особенно когда посмотрел на линию, отделяющую в данном дизайне заголовок от тела вопроса. В этом автор проявил завидную наблюдательнось.

@mordvincevD,

    Т.е. мы объявляем структуру __rcu типа ip_mc_list

НЕТ!

Мы объявили указатель с именем `mc_list` на структуру типа `ip_mc_list`, а `__rcu` это такой атрибут этого указателя. В некоторых случаях он определен, например так

    # define __rcu          __attribute__((noderef, address_space(4)))


а в других 

    # define __rcu

нет, тогда вместо  него cpp подствит пусто.